# Localize the Message Box Buttons in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0

I am in process of localizing my silverlight app. I have a MessageBox as below:

```
MessageBox.Show("Do You Want To Remove Rule: " + dgdProperties.GetColumnValue("Name") + "?", "Removing Rule", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel)
```

I can localize other strings here but is there any way to localize the Button's text...OK/Cancel?

Thanks,
Abdi

Comment: The buttons will be localized to the OS's settings.

Comment: Yes. I also think so. I have a English OS. Is there any way to change the OS Setting to another language in order to test or I have to install another OS?

Answer (score 0):

MessageBox built into silverlight can't be changed.The only way is to create a custom MessageBox (ChildWindow) and put there whatever you need.

Refered from :[Localize Messagebox button](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2db60424-feae-429c-a891-6064abb913ed/how-to-localize-the-caption-of-messagebox-button)